# Accessing Windows Mobile/CE devices without using activesync/WMDC

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, activesync, wmdc

I am currently working on an application that runs on several different Windows Mobile and CE devices.  The project is written in unmanaged C++ using MFC.  This application also comes with a supporting PC app and we programatically transfer files between the two through activesync/WMDC.

We have been running into many different issues because of the need for all PC's using our app need to have activesync/WMDC installed on them.

Is it possible to share information and files between desktop computers and WM devices that do not use activesync/WMDC?  If so, are there libraries or examples of how to do this?

This only has to go one way, the desktop application could do all the work if it could figure out that a device was connected and then move files around. Though it would be more convenient if it worked both ways.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Activesync will be the most reliable method, being the one that will be the same for all windows mobile devices. Beyond that you're looking at a bit of trial & error to see what happens when you connect particular devices to a machine without activesync installed. If you're lucky the devices you care about will show up as an external drive.

You also have the option of working with the activesync protocol at a lower level, but that's not something I'd recommend as that would likely cause problems for people who do have activesync installed.

To get independence from the software on the pc I'd go with something network based instead - assuming the devices have a network connection, that gives a much better user experience than activesync anyway.